# Send compressed requests with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, http, compression

I have looked at simlar questions but they do not cover my scenario. Example:
[Is it possible to enable http compression for requests?](https://serverfault.com/q/56700)

**Scenario**:

- Server A is running a Service which generates large XML files. On Server A, Apache is installed as a Proxy to foward (PUT/POST) the Messages to our Server B.
- Because the files are rather large, I want to compress (e.g. gZip/deflate) the XML before being sent to Server B.
- I can use mod_deflate on Server B (inputfilter) to automatically decompress the message. On Server A, I have also configured mod_deflate (set as outputfilter) but the request is not compressed - only the response from Server B can be then accepted as compressed.

**Question**
How can I configure the Apache on Server A to compress the request body before being sent to Server B?

Restrictions/Further information:

- I cannot modify/implement the compression of the XML in the Service (closed Software).
- I cannot change the scenario to Server B requesting the file.
- Process does not need to be HTTP complaint